# Oncheck event must trigger a function in other component

Tags: angular, event-binding

I have a html page which is combination of two components A and B. I want to display a table that is generated in component B on click of the checkbox that is coming from Component A. Even this oncheck event must be triggered everytime there is a change. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes in principle, but please provide quite a few more details, and better yet, an example in code of what you want. And then show us where you got stuck (or even tell us that you don't know where to start), then somebody might be able to help.

Comment: Since op is only asking for possibility so my answer is yes. You can either use a Service or use Output and Input decorators in components A and B. If using a Service, you will create a member of type EventEmitter in it and subscribe it component B. Trigger event from component A on click event of checkbox and B's subscription will give you the event. If using later approach, Emit event to your parent component from component A using Output decorator. Furthermore, you may pass this event as an input to component B using Input decorator.

Comment: I want to read the event from one component in other component, and whenever the value in parent component changes it should notify the child component that it has changed. 
I don't know how to do this.

Comment: There are many ways to do that in angular. EventEmitter could be nice way to achieve that. [link](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: use a event or a variable, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrv6hs